# Completely Pixelated Font in JavaScript Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, text

I'm making a game with a canvas scaled up such that each pixel is pretty big. I want to display some pixelated text without anti-aliasing but I have idea how I would accomplish this.

Is there I way can do such a thing?

[image: Example]

Comment: How are you drawing your text so far?

Comment: Have you considered to just use a pixely font?

Comment: I'm using ctx.fillText(), and ctx.font to style it. I would use a custom font but I don't know how to draw custom fonts into the canvas.

Comment: Update: I've figured out how to import a custom font and draw it to the canvas, but there is still an anti-aliasing effect.

Comment: I've found the solution! you need to disable font smoothing for all elements in the css.

Comment: If you've found the solution yourself, please consider posting it as an answer to the question and accepting it for people who find this in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the css, you need to disable font smoothing for canvas:

```
canvas{
    font-smooth: never;
    -webkit-font-smoothing : none;
}
```